# How to put character from variable into array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, character

I want to put a character from a variable into a character array in C. Also I want to print the reversed array afterwards as you can see but that's not the issue now.

This is the code I've got so far:

As stdin I'm using a txt-file with "< input.txt" as a command line argument, and it has 57 characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int counter = 0;
  char character_array[57];
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  char character = 0;

  // While EOF is not encountered read each character
  while (counter != EOF) 
  {
    // Print each character
    printf("%c", counter);
    // Continue getting characters from the stdin/input file
    counter = getchar(stdin);
    // Put each character into an array
    character_array[j] = { counter };
    j = j + 1;
  }

  // Print the array elements in reverse order
  for (i = 58; i > 0; i--)
  {
    character = character_array[i];
    printf("%c", character);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My IDE says at line 35 after the first curly brace "expected expression".

```
// Put each character into an array
    character_array[j] = { counter };
```

So I guess it fails there. I assume I cannot just put the character variable like that in the array? How would I go about doing this otherwise?

PS: I'm new to C.

Comment: have you tried to remove the `{` and `}` around `counter`?

Comment: `character_array[j] = counter;` But it is better to use `scanf( "%s",  character_array );` and read the whole string at once. Note that you character_array array is better to be longer!

Comment: and `getchar(stdin)` --> `getchar()`

Comment: Thank you all, removing the curly braces worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `{` and `}` in that line so that it looks like :

```
character_array[j] =  counter ;
```

Improved code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int counter = 0;
  char character_array[57];
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  //char character = 0; Unused variable

  // While EOF is not encountered read each character
  while ((counter = getchar()) != EOF) 
  {
    // Print each character
    printf("%c", counter);
    character_array[j] = counter;
    j++;
  }
  for (i = j - 1; i >= 0; i--) /* Array indices start from zero, and end at length - 1 */
  {
    printf("%c", character_array[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
character_array[j] = counter;
```

Just that simple i think